# How to replace wifi password?

Tags: iphone, network, wifi, password

I have saved the wifi password for our network on an iPhone 5c.  In the meantime the wifi username and password has changed.

So what I had tried so far:

1. Go to Settings -> Wifi
2. Choose the wifi network's "i" icon
3. Choose "Forget This Network"
4. Choose "Forget"
5. Back to the wifi settings
6. Select the wifi network's "i" icon again
7. Select "Join Network"
8. Safari opens and ask for a user name and password
9. Enter the user name and password
10. Choose Done

Next time when I join the network again, on my on-screen keyboard, I go to "Passwords".

The only options I see is the OLD username and password so that the new one that I just had entered is missing.

How can I replace the OLD wifi username and password so that I do not have to enter it manually again?

Comment: Do you have 'Ask to Join Networks' setting turned ON? If you turn it OFF then known networks will be joined automatically and if you have wrong password, then it will ask for correct one and save it.

Comment: @ranklord I see an "Auto-Join" and a "Auto-Login" option. Which one are referring to? I'm on iOS 9.3.5

Comment: About [this](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202639)

Comment: @ranklord Thanks, but my old password still shows instead of the new one.

Comment: It seems like "Forget this network" only forget the network, not the password.

Comment: Looks like I've missed one key point. Go to Settings -> Safari -> General, Authorise yourself and try to update your password there.

Comment: @Koning I'm very sure that's not intended behaviour as I have used forget network to do that kind of stuff many times

Comment: @ranklord Sorry I only saw your comment after I posted the solution. Please post it as an answer and I will select it as the correct answer.

Comment: @Koning, glad we've managed to solve your problem! :)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Settings -> Safari -> General, Authorise yourself and try to update your password there.